# There was an error completing your request-google-home simulator page issue

Tags: google-home

I have try to test my project in google home simulator. up to yesterday it was working but today it is showing error "There was an error completing your request"
URL: "https://console.actions.google.com/project/tell-you-profile/simulator/"

Comment: Most of us aren't permitted to the project. Can you include some screen shots of the simulator and all the tabs in it? Check your fulfillment webhook and see if there are any errors there?

Comment: I have changed some configuration. now fixed thx @prisoner

Answer (score 10):

I was just having the same issue starting my simulator.   The problem was:  I was signed into Google Chrome, with my other (personal) email address.  Once I went to cloud.google.com, signed out, and signed back in with the account that matched the needed user for the Cloud Services, the simulator loads fine.

This was my simulator issue (just to confirm):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most times this error is caused by an error in your fulfillment server. Check your code to make sure it compiled or is interpreted correctly and then check your logs for any errors.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, everything was working fine as I was switching between my ngrok server pointing to my localhost and my live server on the cloud by frequently pushing a new action.js. All of sudden everything stopped working. First I was getting errr updating my action.js and now I cannot get in to the simulator on the web. I see "There was an error completing your request". I reverted my action.js to the last state which worked perfectly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a different question. I suggest posting a new question, include screen shots where possible, and clarify what you mean by "my assistant app is non existent".

Comment: I refreshed the page and could not see my assistant app box, there was only a big plus sign within a square to "add/import project". I panicked for a second, refreshed the page a min later and my project was back. I have to mention I left the project for about 30 min and once I came back everything started to fine as before. It feels as if it was a temporary service problem. Thanks anyway for the quick response. :)